# ajax calls with out redirecting the page

Tags: php, ajax, web-services

my process is to call a web service before loading a page that contain a form with some fields ,the fileds organisation,location,building in the form are obtained from the response from the web service call.the fields organistion,building and location are drop downs ,the organisation is selected ,then location is selected after that building is selected,now there is a filed called expiry date ,inorder to get the expiry date i must call a web service by giving the location name as the json input to the web service ,i would like to stick on the same page and get the response for the expiry date,i thought that i will use ajax for that ,i really dont know how to do it can any one help me ? I got some code here can any one redirect me to do some thing done with this code

```
$.ajax( {
type:'Get',
url:'http://mysite.com/mywebservice',
success:function(data) {
alert(data);
}

})
```

Comment: yes ajx is best for this , wt is ur problem ?

Comment: i would like to call another wb service for that i would like to know where should i paste the above code

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to call a php script to get your results.

Write your php script exactly like you would for generating a normal web page except that instead of outputting (echo) HTML, you output XML or JSON.

Comment: i would like to show you some of my code ,the addoperator.php is the file that perform web service call to get organisation,location,and building ( here is the code http://pastebin.com/1PYTdxp6),i would like to call a addoperator1.php to get the expiry date by giving the location name as input is here http://pastebin.com/5k0iMBQB